# how to perform ctrl+F and search for a number through robot class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please help me!
After navigating to a page, selenium webdriver should press `control + F` and search for a number using robot class.
I have tried using actions class, but `control + F` is not working.
So,i have used robot class.

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

`control + F` is working.But,how to send the number i wanted to search/find.

Also,if possible, please tell me how to search for a particular string from a page using set of pattern.

update:
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='regno']")).sendKeys(regno);
    System.out.println(regno);

```
// clicking on find button
dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Find']")).click();
Robot rb = new Robot();
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(regno);
Clipboard cp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
cp.setContents(ss, null);

// ctrl+F
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);

// Releasing Ctrl and F key
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

Thread.sleep(2000);
// ctrl+v 
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

But, the value present in regno is not getting copied in ctrl+f window.

Comment: What are you searching for with CTRL+F? What do you plan to do with it? There might be a better way to do this.

Comment: i have to search for a number using 'search by number'.Then,from a list of 1000 records,the matched record will be highlighted and  displayed in the page which is a link.Then,i ahve to click on that link.

Comment: Why not use a locator to find it? It would be much easier than trying to control the browser find feature. Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: I'm sorry.I couldnt share the page link.I thought i couldnt find the element using locator.Thats why,i wanted to use robot class.How to locate element i.e ., 508767676788 and click on it.                                                                    
  Html code :   <a href="javascript:openWin('PageName.htm?id=100-1200&amp;status=44');">508767676788</a>

Comment: If you already know the number, e.g. 508767676788, then you can use an XPath like `//a[.='508767676788']`.

Answer (score 0):

Search also we need to perform using Robot class, The following code copied the search content to clipboard, then Ctrl+V using robot class will paste the search string in Find box

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("Search String");
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V)
```

Comment: Robot rb = new Robot();
 StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(regno);
 Clipboard cp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
       cp.setContents(ss, null);
        //ctrl+F
       rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
       rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
       rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);    
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);  I have tried using the above code.ctrl+f is working but the regno is not pasted to find box.

Comment: The problem with your declaration is, Ctrl and F key was not released. So it was assumed that Ctrl and F key is pressed.  Also, give some time gap between the two operations. The changes are updated in your code snippet. Kindly try and let me know

Comment: tanq so much.I gave 1 sec gap after releasing ctrl+v.Then,it worked